# electrical safety for UK -> NL move

Tags: mains

We are planning on moving back into the EU. We have a lifestyle of UK based appliances, and will need to update/refit/replace them all.

I see that EN / "Europäische Norm" is very well specified https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_EN_standards, but to read that much text, I think would take enough time to do another degree.

1. What is a PAC test equivalent in NL?
2. Is a 16amp mains-ring the standard for basic things like laptops in NL (type F plug)?  Is there standard for lower power electricals?
3. NL domestic voltage is quite close to the UK spec.  Can I just swap the plugs over? https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/netherlands/

Comment: Ring mains is UK-specific wiring and it is largely irrelevant how your plugs are wired. Depends on country but kitchens usually have a few 16A fused sockets and a few 10A fused sockets. The voltage is also device specific but likely close enough unless specifically not allowed.

Comment: The voltage specifications is same in EU (UK, NL, FR, ...) 230V 50Hz and the type F, E, C plug are full compatibles.

Comment: The most exotic sockets you might come across in the Netherlands are [Perilex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perilex) sockets, used primarily for heavier kitchen equipment like induction cookers and ovens. They can be wired up as either 3-phase 16 A (L1, L2, L3 and N) or as dual single phase 32 A (2N, 2L, non-standardized). Also remember many/most households have a 3-phase mains supply, usually split into 3 separate 230 V supplies for reqular household equipment, with some heavier equipment like EV chargers, cooking and heat pumps running directly off 3 phase power.